# Bind Super + I/J/K/L to arrow keys

Tags: keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys

I want to bind <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>/<kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>L</kbd> keys to arrows. Let say if I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> it would be the same as pressing <kbd>↑</kbd>. If I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> it would be the same as pressing <kbd>↓</kbd>.

I have edited `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/myLayout` before for switching other keys, but I don't know how to bind the <kbd>Super</kbd> modifier (I had no problem with the shift or the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> modifiers because they corresponded to different levels).

The question is, how to bind <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>/<kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>L</kbd> to arrows (<kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>)?